# Changing a POST variable that matches a string

Tags: php

I'm writing a simple PHP form. For one of the fields in the form I want to replace the contents of the variable if it matches the text in the field placeholder so it isn't sent in the email.

```
<p>Base Colour Preference
        <input type="text" name="basecolour" value="ENTER BASE COLOUR">
</p>
```

+

```
if ($basecolour == "ENTER BASE COLOUR") {
    $basecolour = "No colour chosen";
}
```

Should change the variable, shouldn't it? Instead it's emailing the original string of "ENTER BASE COLOUR". Here's the whole code:

```
<?php 

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$basecolour = $_POST['basecolour'];
$highlightcolour = $_POST['highlightcolour'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$header = "from <$email>";

$message = "From: $name \nBase Colour: $basecolour \nHighlight Colour: $highlightcolour \nComments: $comments";

$to = "me@me.com.au";

$subject ="Preorder Registration";

if ($basecolour == "ENTER BASE COLOUR") {
    $basecolour = "No colour chosen";
}

if ($name == "YOUR NAME") {
echo "Please enter your name";
}

if ($email == "YOUR EMAIL") {
    echo "Please enter your email address";
}

else {
mail($to, $subject, $message, $header) or die("error!");
echo "DONE";
}

?>
```

Any help is most appreciated! I'm still learning :)

Comment: "I'm still learning" Learn how to use input validation and escaping. IMHO that's the first one to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this

```
$message = "From: $name \nBase Colour: $basecolour \nHighlight Colour: $highlightcolour \nComments: $comments";
```

after your **`if`** statement !

**Reason** : Because you have already assigned the value `ENTER BASE COLOUR` to `$message` variable.

Answer (score 0):

My strong suggestion not an effective answer :

You should use HTML5 placeholder attribute instead of inserting it in the value because all the modern browsers are supporting html5 now. And then
validate your form if they are mandatory or check null in your form processing and give appropriate value in your message body.

```
  <input type="text" name="basecolour" value="" placeholder="ENTER BASE COLOUR">
```